# How can I split a MultiSelectList into n number of items and wrap each partitioned group of items with markup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Are there any nice ways to break up the below multiSelectList and wrap n number of items? Possibly using some linq extensions?

For example wrapping 4 items at a time in a <div> before adding it to divTag.InnerHtml? obviously having to check first if there are enough items?

```
foreach (SelectListItem item in multiSelectList)
{
    divTag.InnerHtml += String.Format("<label for=\"{0}_{1}\">{3}" +
                                      "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"{0}\" id=\"{0}_{1}\" value=\"{1}\" {2} />" +
                                      "</label>",
                                      propertyName,
                                      item.Value,
                                      selectedValues.Contains(item.Value) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "",
                                      item.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) (search for it on NuGet) has extension `Batch` which allows you to make batches from any sequence. Maybe thats what you are looking for.

```
foreach(var batch in multiSelectList.Batch(4))
{
   // every batch will contain 4 items (well, except last one possibly)
   foreach(SelectListItem item in batch)
   {
       //...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried it out and it works well.